# How can I install mobile support on C++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt

**I have not found anything,which can solve this problem,so I go there in hope I can solve it.**

I install all components,which I needed

[image]

and I can not find mobile application project

[image]

Comment: Are you using [this](http://www.qt.io/mobile-app-development/)?

Comment: What version of Qt have you downloaded?

Comment: I think newest version

Answer (score 2):

The list of target platforms will available on the next steps of the wizard. Just see the video of creating new mobile project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFGRr0DV3oM

Qt docs: [**Creating a Mobile Application**](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/qtcreator-accelbubble-example.html)

Comment: I just did this yesterday, and as long as the toolchain for the platform is installed and the e.g. Android or Windows phone Qt versions are selected (none of the others are needed), you can select the mobile platforms you want as project kits.